# Running scripts in another path in matlab doesn't work at all

Tags: matlab, path, weka

I wrote a function *A* in matlab that takes inputs and reshapes them. Next of it calls another function in sub directories *B* with these reshaped arguments. The function *B* should be executed a code on directory that have passed to it. The function *B* works with string of directory explicitly passed to it. But when i generate string of same directory and passes to it. it does not execute.

here is the error:

> Undefined function 'B' for input arguments of type 'char'.

the code of function *A*

```
function [ Data ] = A( DataSet,fileName )
root = getenv('Project');
addpath /Subdirectory
Data = B(strcat(root,'\Features\',DataSet,'\',fileName));
end
```

Comment: Can you confirm that `strcat(root,'\Features\',DataSet,'\',fileName)` gives you the string you want? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Also use the `fullfile()` function to build path and directory strings instead of `strcat()`. It grants cross platform compatibility.

Comment: @eigenchris when i execute `strcat(root,'\Features\',DataSet,'\',fileName)` in command window and copy/paste result to windows explorer it opens the file.

Comment: @ lmNt `fullfile()` function has the same problem.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in your `B.m` file and see if MATLAB enters the function at all? If so, try stepping through it to see what goes wrong. If you aren't getting an explicit error message, the problem might be `B.m` itself rather than your path.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try with 
`addpath ./Subdirectory`.
Besides, it seems that you are working on Windows (because of the backslashes '\Features',etc), so maybe you should try `addpath .\Subdirectory`